# C# Singleton used as a picture buffer

Tags: c#, memory, reference, singleton

i want to use the singleton pattern to create a buffer where all needed pictures are stored.

Something like that:

```
public sealed class BaseBuffer
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Bitmap> pictures = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();

    public static Bitmap GetPicture(string name, ref Bitmap output)
    {
        //In case the pictureBuffer does not contain the element already
        if (!pictures.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            //Try load picture from resources
            try
            {
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Resources." + name + ".png"));
                pictures.Add(name, bmp);
                return bmp;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Picture {0} cannot be found.", name);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return pictures[name];
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Now im not sure. Does the "GetPicture" method return a copy of the picture or does it return a reference?

The application will need a few pictures which are displayed verry often on different Applications/Forms. Because of that it would be better to have only references to the pictures than copying them around.

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll return a reference to the `Bitmap` (as it is defined as a class) held within the dictionary. So no it doesn't return a distinct copy. Changes to the bitmap returned will be observed in the dictionary also as they will be the same underlying object. I'm not sure what you are doing with your `ref Bitmap output` as it doesn't appear to be used.

Also, `TryGetValue` on the dictionary will perform slightly better if this is called often:

```
Bitmap bmp;

if (!pictures.TryGetValue(name, out bmp))
{
    bmp = new Bitmap(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Resources." + name + ".png"));
    pictures.Add(name, bmp);
}

return bmp;
```

Comment: Im sorry, the "out Bitmap output" was just a try (return vs out) but i prefer the return. Copy Paste mistake ;-)

Thanks for the information / tips.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about that, butIi guess instead of doing `return bmp;` you should do `output=bmp;`  and so on. Otherwise you could get rid of the parameter.

I also think, that even `return bmp;` and so on would return a reference but not a copy of the `Bitmap` stored in the dict. so either way would be fine...